# Calculate the average of array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I got this Javascript exercise. The average should be 11.2, but my program returned 5420502.4.

---

Define an empty array. Also create two functions:

addNumber() reads a value from a text input field on the HTML document (id="num") and adds it at the end of the array.

printInfo() outputs the amount of elements in the array to the console, then the average of their values.

The HTML document has two buttons for calling the functions.

---

```js
var arr = [];

function addNumber() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    return arr.push(num);
}

function printInfo() {
    var len = arr.length;
    console.log("The array has " + len + " elements.");
    
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        total += arr[i]; // replace arr[i] with +arr[i]
    }
    var avg = total / len;
  // additionally render result to UI
  document.getElementById("info").innerText = avg;
    return console.log("The average of the values is " + avg);
}
```

```css
.outerStyle { border: 2px solid black; width: 45%; }
.inpStyle { padding: 10px; margin: 10px; }
button { margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="outer" class="outerStyle">
  <div class="inpStyle">
    <label for="num">Enter number: </label>
    <input id="num" type="number" />
  </div>
  <button id="addBtn" onclick="addNumber()">Add</button>
  <button id="printInfo" onClick="printInfo()">Print Info</button>
  <hr/>
  <div id="info" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why not add the relevant HTML and turn this into an actual runnable snippet?

Comment: Also, `return arr.push(num);` should be `arr.push(+num);` (you're pushing strings right now, not numbers, and returning something is pointless in both functions)

Comment: At a glance my *guess* is that you're appending *strings* instead of adding *numbers*.  When you debug, examine the value of `total` and confirm it is what you expect.

Comment: @David - no need to guess, the code snippet shows clearly that they are pushing the `.value` of an input element, which will always be a string.

Comment: OP, the question has been edited. The stack snippets may be used to provide such (& lot more, actually - I'm still very new & learning) code which may help answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from your input is a string. So, it will concatenate in to `total`. If your input value was 1 and you added it to the array twice, your array would consist of 2 strings, "1" and "1". Then, you're adding this, which makes "11" because you're adding strings together.

You'll want to use something like [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string to a number first.

```
function addNumber() {
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    return arr.push(parseInt(num));
}
```

Comment: what if '11.5'?)

Comment: @vanowm Nah, I'm downvoting this answer as "not useful" because this is a) definitely a dupe, and b) encouraging newbies to post trivial issues here, which isn't supposed to happen. Dislike it all you want, but it's simply not how SO is supposed to work. Reference: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)